# Combine documents in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a huge MongoDB collection (~0.5 Million documents).

The structure is like this:

```
{'_id': '.....',
'passid':'ag325gdtew',
'text': '.......',
'count': '.......',
'title': '......',
'body': '.......'
}
```

The field `passid` is the same in many documents and I want to combine them with a different way for each field.

I want to:

- keep the same `passid`
- join text and title in each document (text+title) and then join the final string in one field on the new document (text1+text2+text3)
- create a field list with each count [count1, count2, count3]
- remove the body field

So the new document will be like this:

```
{'_id': '.....',
'passid':'ag325gdtew',
'text': '.......', (string)
'count': ['..','...','..'] (list)
}
```

At the moment, I am doing it with Python but the file is huge and the script keeps running for hours.

What I have done:

- aggregate with group to retrieve a list with unique `passid`
- iterate in that list for every `passid`
- use the find(`passid`) to retrieve a cursor of all the documents with the same `passid`
- do the joins and appends of the strings and lists with python
- delete the old documents
- save the new one

As I said, it is really time-consuming. Do you know any faster way to do it?

Here is the code:

```
passids= db.collection.aggregate({ "$group": {"_id": '$passid'}})

for i in passids['result']:
    doc = {}
    doc['passid'] = i['_id']
    documents = db.collection.find({"passid": i['_id']})
    doc['count'] = []
    doc['text'] = ""

    for d in documents:
        doc['text'] = doc['text'] + " " + d['text']
        doc['text'] = doc['text'] + " " + d['title']
        doc['count'].append(d['count'])
        db.collection.remove(d)
    db.collection.save(doc)
```

Comment: You reallt don't actually point out which part is "time consuming" or what your actual desired result is. We can presume you are trying to "re-form" documents into a new collection. Can you show what work you are doing? And state whether this is a "one-off" task or something you regularly need to do in your question.

Comment: It is something I will do only once. I thought my explanations were clear about the way I am doing it. But I will post here the code as well in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to avoid a lot of network traffic between your application and the datbase your best option generally will be to try to run the code as close as possible (in network terms) to the database for the best speed.

Where this is not possible, and really only should be used in "one-off" operations you can make use of running code on the server using [**`db.eval()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/)

> **WARNING** You **must** carefully read the manual page for [**`db.eval()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/) before even considering usage. While the fastest way to get things done there are major drawbacks to consider:
>
> 1. This **will** obtain a write lock on the database for the entire duration of execution.
> 2. In addition to the write lock being obtained, due to the single threaded nature of the JavaScript implementation, no other tasks such as "mapReduce" jobs that use the JavaScript interpreter will be able to run.
> 3. This will just not be possible to run on a sharded cluster and if your hosting is using authentication, the user account will need special permissions beyond basic read and write in order to execute the task.

Once you have considered all of the above, you can take your head out of the sand, acknowledge that the method exists and move on.

As long as you can deal with output to a different collection you can start with [**`mapReduce`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/), which sort of simplifies the logic

You can define a mapper:

```js
var mapper = function() {
   
   var passid = this.passid;
   delete this["_id"];
   delete this["body"];

   emit( passid, this );

};
```

And then define a reducer:

```js
var reducer = function(key,values) {

    var reducedObject = {
        "text": "",
        "count": []
    };

    values.forEach(function(value) {
        reducedObject.text = reducedObject.text + " " + value.text;
        reducedObject.text = reducedObject.text + " " + value.title;
        reducedObject.push( value.count );
    });

    return reducedObject;

};
```

Then you can run the mapReduce operation:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    mapper,
    reducer,
    {
        "out": { "replace": "newcollection" }
    }
)
```

With mapReduce output being what it is, you don't want that in your final output so you can change it like this:

```js
db.eval(function() {
    db.newcollection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
        var newDoc = {};
        for ( var k in doc.values ) {
            newDoc[k] = doc.values[k];
        }
        db.newcollection.update({ _id: doc._id }, newDoc );
    });
})
```

That will put things into a reshaped collection, and you could even look at moving that between databases in order to get around locking issues. This still may leave you in a position where to need to swap this with the original collection, but there are ways to do that.

---

As an alternate you can basically just cut to it and run the `db.eval()` operations right off. So this basically translates the process to the corresponding JavaScript:

```js
db.eval(function() {

    var lastid = "";
    var counter = 0;
    var text = "";
    var count = [];

    db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
        if ( (doc.passid != lastid) && (counter != 0) ) {
            db.collection.update(
                { "_id": doc._id },
                { 
                    "passid": lastid,
                    "text": text,
                    "count": count
                }
            );
            text = "";
            count = [];
        }
        text = text + " " + doc.text;
        text = text + " " doc.title;
        count.push( doc.count );
        counter++;
        lastid = passid;
    });
})
```

So bulk changing of documents is never a nice thing, but there are some ways to approach this and keep all the operations on the server.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, most of the slowness in this type of operations with mongo comes from round-trips to the  database, so try to make as few calls to it as you can. If your documents are small enough (as they seem for your example) so that the entire collection fits in memory, you can save a huge amount of time by making a single multiple insert and multiple delete:

```
passids= db.collection.aggregate({ "$group": {"_id": '$passid'}})

new_docs = []

for i in passids['result']:
    doc = {}
    doc['passid'] = i['_id']
    documents = db.collection.find({"passid": i['_id']})
    doc['count'] = []
    doc['text'] = ""

    for d in documents:
        doc['text'] = doc['text'] + " " + d['text']
        doc['text'] = doc['text'] + " " + d['title']
        doc['count'].append(d['count'])

   new_docs.append(doc)

# Instead of removing all the documents one by one, 
# dropping the collection is much faster
db.collection.drop()

db.collection.insert(new_docs)
```

To err on the safe side, I'd save the documents in a new collection and only drop the old one after checking that everything looks fine.